# Association named 'echo_producer_apis' was not found on EchoProducerApi; perhaps you misspelled it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I think I am doing some naming error so please help me out...!!

```
class EchoProducerApi < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :echo_practice_api    
end

class EchoPracticeApi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :echo_producer_apis
end

@producer_data = EchoProducerApi.joins(:echo_producer_apis).select("echo_practice_apis.*,echo_producer_apis.*").paginate(:page => params[:page] , :per_page => 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
belongs_to :echo_producer_apis
```

to

```
belongs_to :echo_producer_api
```

With `belongs_to :echo_producer_apis`, Rails will look for a class name called `EchoPracticeApis`, but you have `EchoPracticeApi`. That's why it is not working. Change to the association name will fix it.

Note: Generally association name for `belongs_to` and `has_one` should be a *singular*.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Rails relationships and associations are self-explanatory. `belongs_to` essentially means that an instance of your object belongs_to only one object of other class, therefore you should specify it as a singular value. Hence you should change from:

```
class EchoPracticeApi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :echo_producer_apis
end
```

To:

```
class EchoPracticeApi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :echo_producer_api
end
```

Comment: after changing the code 
Unknown key: :foregin_key. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :foreign_type, :polymorphic, :touch, :counter_cache

Comment: class EchoPracticeApi < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :echo_producer_api, :foregin_key => 'practiceTypeID'
end

Comment: in echo_practice_api table I have a column practiceTypeID_id

Comment: Please carefully read the error message. It has your answer. Spelling of foregin_key is wrong. It should be foreign_key

Comment: Actually I have posted wrong question sorry..I have corrected the foreign_key issue .. but after that  get another MySQL error/
 .My question is
(I am new to rails )
 Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'echo_practice_apis.echo_producer_api_id' in 'on clause': SELECT  echo_practice_apis.*,echo_producer_apis.* FROM `echo_producer_apis` INNER JOIN `echo_practice_apis` ON `echo_practice_apis`.`echo_producer_api_id` = `echo_producer_apis`.`id` LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Comment: Your model that has belongs_to should have the foreign_key of the association table. In your case `echo_practice_apis` should have a column named `echo_producer_api_id`